# Gatsby - SSR i18n translation are loaded on client

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, i18next

I have a multilingual gatsby website, I try to improve the lighthouse performance score, so i followed [this guide](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/blog/2017-10-17-building-i18n-with-gatsby/#ssr) to generate my page with the translation in the html. Here is my `gatsby-ssr.js` file

```
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server'
import Backend from 'i18next-sync-fs-backend'
import i18n from "./src/locales/i18n"

const namespaces = [...my ns...];

export const replaceRenderer = ({ bodyComponent, replaceBodyHTMLString }) => {
    i18n
      .use(Backend)
      .init({
        initImmediate: false,
        backend: {
          loadPath: 'src/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
        },
      })
      // load the common namespace
      .loadNamespaces(namespaces, (err) => {
        replaceBodyHTMLString(renderToString(bodyComponent))
      })
  }
```

My `i18n.js` file :

```
import i18n from "i18next";
import Backend from "i18next-xhr-backend";
import LanguageDetector from "i18next-browser-languagedetector";
import { reactI18nextModule } from "react-i18next";

i18n
    .use(Backend)
    .use(LanguageDetector)
    .use(reactI18nextModule)
    .init({
        fallbackLng: "fr",
        ns: ['translation'],
        defaultNS: 'translation',
        load: 'languageOnly',
        debug: false,

        interpolation: {
            escapeValue: false, // not needed for react!!
        },

        react: {
            wait: true,
        },
    });

export default i18n;
```

I use the HOC `withNamespaces` from react-i18next (v8) in my page like that `export default withNamespaces('home')(IndexPage);`

This works well because the generated HTML has all the text translated but when I access to my page the client will load a second time the translation and re-render the page, this cause a flickering on the page and big layout shift so lighthouse really not like it. I believe this is in relation with `i18next-xhr-backend` but I'm stuck.

I expect my page to not load the translation on page load, because the html has already the text translated so I don't need to load translation again